# Retrieve randomly generated child ID from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have Firebase generating random keys for my records in a Swift app. How do I go about retrieving that key if I want to change a specific record? In my example below, I'm marking a task complete but when I hit the button it doesn't work as intended because I am not referencing the particular task but to reference the task I need the randomly generated key.

```
 func doneHit(cell:TaskCell) {
        if let ip = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
            var task = tasksInSectionArray[ip.section][ip.row]
            let tasksRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("tasks")
            ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                let doneRef = tasksRef.childByAppendingPath("\(snapshot.key)/done")
                if task.done == false {
                    task.done = true
                    cell.checkBox.image = UIImage(named: "checkedbox")
                    doneRef.setValue(task.done)
                }
                else {
                    task.done = false
                    cell.checkBox.image = UIImage(named: "uncheckedbox")
                    doneRef.setValue(task.done)
                }
                let completedByRef = tasksRef.childByAppendingPath("\(snapshot.key)/completedBy")
                if task.done == true {
                    completedByRef.setValue(self.user)
                    cell.detailLabel.text = "Completed By: \(self.user)"
                }
                else {
                    completedByRef.setValue("")
                    cell.detailLabel.text = ""
                }
                })
        }
    }
```

My Firebase structure:

1. tasks

   - randomly generated ID

     - title:
     - description:
   - randomly generated ID

     - title:
     - description:

**Update 1:**

I have updated my code to get the IDs for all of the tasks but the functionality of updating the backend isn't working properly. It is only letting update the tasks created in the app. There are 150 tasks that I imported using the web Dashboard. Those are the ones I can't get to update.

```
func doneHit(cell:TaskCell) {
        if let ip = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
            var task = tasksInSectionArray[ip.section][ip.row]
            let tasksRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("tasks")
            var taskID = ""
            tasksRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                for task in snapshot.children {
                    let _tasks = task as! FDataSnapshot
                    let id = _tasks.key
                    print(id)
                    taskID = id
                }
                let doneRef = tasksRef.childByAppendingPath("\(taskID)/done")
                if task.done == false {
                    task.done = true
                    cell.checkBox.image = UIImage(named: "checkedbox")
                    doneRef.setValue(task.done)
                }
                else {
                    task.done = false
                    cell.checkBox.image = UIImage(named: "uncheckedbox")
                    doneRef.setValue(task.done)
                }
                let completedByRef = tasksRef.childByAppendingPath("\(taskID)/completedBy")
                if task.done == true {
                    completedByRef.setValue(self.user)
                    cell.detailLabel.text = "Completed By: \(self.user)"
                }
                else {
                    completedByRef.setValue("")
                    cell.detailLabel.text = ""
                }
                })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't you want to call `observeSingleEventOfType` on `tasksRef`?

Comment: yeah. you aren't wrong there but that still doesn't solve my problem. it just creates another instance of tasks and puts the changes there instead of updating the actual task the changes were made on.

Comment: Either way, if you observe an event of type `.Value`, the `snapshot` will be an array of tasks (in your case) rather than one task on its own. If you want to loop through the individual tasks, you should use `for task in snapshot.children { }` and cast `task` to an `FDataSnapshot`.

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't hold the ID for that task. that only holds the children for that ID. at least thats what I have seen in my testing.

Comment: Once you cast `task` to `FDataSnapshot`, you can access the ID with `task.key` :)

Comment: I see what you are saying. Ok. Let me try that.

Comment: Sure, see my answer if you're unsure what I meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tasksRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    for task in snapshot.children {
        guard let taskSnapshot = task as? FDataSnapshot else {
            continue
        }

        let id = task.key
        // do other things
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't completely work. It oddly works on any task I create within the app but not on any other task. When I print out the ids to the console it prints a long list of all of them but when I try to edit on of the tasks, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @MichaelWilliams I'd like to help you solve this issue. What exactly do you want to edit about a task? And how did you try to do that with the `taskSnapshot` I've given you?

Comment: Everything I'm editing is in my code in the description of the question. I'm trying to change the "done" Bool value and the completedBy String value. I did exactly what you told me to do and it works for IDs generated by the childByAutoID method but for some reason it won't update data that was imported. The imported data has sequential IDs (0-150) that were generated by Firebase and the other task has the randomly generarated characters from that method. Also, this method has worked before. What changed is adding sections to the table view. Do you think that's it?

Comment: I'm not sure how your `doneRef` is defined, but in case you're using code similar to the code in my answer, it should be something like `let doneRef = tasksRef.childByAppendingPath("\(taskSnapshot.key)/done")`. Is that what you have?

Comment: thats exactly what i have. If I click on the task that I created in-app, it works fine. if I click on any other task, it changes that in-app created task as well. It adds a check mark locally like its supposed to but it doesn't change anything on the backend to that task.

Comment: So are you saying the backend is never changed by this code?

Comment: I'm saying the task created in the app is changed when the check box is checked (done Bool is changed) but the other tasks don't change or change the task created in the app. When I add a print statement outside of the for loop, it always prints the ID of the task that was created in the app.

Comment: I think I figured it out. the loop is a string and is only grabbing the last iteration of the for loop which is happens to be the in-app created task. so...I think it needs indexPath.row and section. I am still trying to figure out how to incorporate section because it now works in the first section but not the next.

Comment: Interesting. The `for`-loop in my answer loops through all tasks, but you only need to update one task, right?

Comment: So how do you select the right one, based on the `TaskCell`?

Comment: yeah TaskCell is the visual end of the cells in the tableview

Comment: I get that, but how do you determine the id of the task you need to update in the database?

Comment: Before I added sections, i just used indexPath.row of a local array("tasks") of Task(my struct). Now I need to also incorporate indexPath.section. I have it for cellforRow but I just need to figure out how to incorporate it into the button

Comment: I see. As long as you don't have a way to select the right `Task`, it makes sense that not the right entries in the database are updated. You said you have a `struct` named `Task`, an easy fix would be to store the auto-generated Firebase id in there. Then when someone interacts with a `TaskCell`, you pick the corresponding `Task` based on the `indexPath`, and then you use the `id` to update the database.

Comment: genius! thank you SO much. I can't believe I didn't think of that. everything seems to work as intended.

Answer (score 27):

To create a randomly generated key you need to use `childByAutoId()` (which I can't see in your example code).
This will return a Firebase reference you could use and which will return the key with it's `.key` property

```
var post1Ref = ref.childByAutoId()
post1Ref.setValue(post1)

var postId = post1Ref.key
```

See documentation [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html)

Comment: I know how to create the key. I have that already in another portion of the code. I create my tasks in another view and push them back over.

Comment: @MichaelWilliams So can you use the .key on the ref?

Comment: see my updated post with my json structure. I can only get to "tasks" with ref because I don't know how to access the task's ID. Would it be something I would pass back from where I create the tasks? I'm gonna try that.

Comment: As in my example, you get a new ref (see post1ref) when you call `childByAutoId()`. then use `.key` and with the result use `ref.childByAppendingPath(keyYouGot)`

Comment: How does this work with data imported into Firebase? There is not creation variable when you import so how do I reference a key that I did not create by using childByAutoID?

Comment: What method is used to `import` the data?

Comment: I manually imported the data using a json file through the Dashboard online. it would be odd if they allowed you to import data but not allow you to access the IDs that they generate when you import them.

Answer (score 1):

Following Tim's answer for Swift 3 and Firebase 4 I had to use the below

```
for task in snapshot.children {
            guard let taskSnapshot = task as? DataSnapshot else {
                continue
            }

            let id = taskSnapshot.key
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Ron's answer involves generating the key first and then using it to set value:

```
let autoId = databaseReference.childByAutoId().key
databaseReference.child(autoId).setValue(YOUR_VALUE)
```