# Get current child ID from Firebase using UITableViewController

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have almost the same question as here: [Firebase get child ID swift ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710960/firebase-get-child-id-swift-ios) and slightly different than this question [Retrieve randomly generated child ID from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210424/retrieve-randomly-generated-child-id-from-firebase).

I have a UITableViewController where users can create there own channels. Those channels can be viewed by everyone, and everyone can tap on one of the channels, and gets into a new view. Now when the user taps on any of those cells, I want to get that current channel ID, the user just tapped on.

My database is looking like this: [image: channel database]

Now my question is: How can I get that current ID (-KdD6[...]Q0Q)? The answer from question 2 would do the trick for the creator of the room, but can not be used by other users since they did not created the key. The answer from question number 1 can maybe be used, but as of now, it just loops through every random key. But I need that key that is related to the channel the user is currently in. Below is some code to show how I make channels as of now. Thanks in advance. Edit: Here is all of my code. I now get an error "value of type [Channel] has no member 'name'"  at didSelectRow function.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Foundation

enum Section: Int {
    case createNewChannelSection = 0
    case currentChannelsSection
}

extension multiplayerChannelView: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}

class multiplayerChannelView: UITableViewController {


    // MARK: Properties
    var channels: [Channel] = []
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    var filteredChannels = [Channel]()
    private lazy var channelRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("channels")
    private var channelRefHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle?
    var senderDisplayName: String?
    var newChannelTextField: UITextField?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Rooms"
        observeChannels()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
    deinit {
        if let refHandle = channelRefHandle {
            channelRef.removeObserver(withHandle: refHandle)
        }
    }
    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        filteredChannels = channels.filter { Channel in
            return (Channel.name.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil)
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    @IBAction func createChannel(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let name = newChannelTextField?.text {
            let newChannelRef = channelRef.childByAutoId()
            let channelItem = [ // 3
                "name": name
            ]
            newChannelRef.setValue(channelItem)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
    private func observeChannels() {
        channelRefHandle = channelRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in // 1
            let channelData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject> // 2
            let id = snapshot.key
            if let name = channelData["name"] as! String!, name.characters.count > 0 { // 3
                self.channels.append(Channel(id: id, name: name))
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                print("Error! Could not decode channel data")
            }
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let currentSection: Section = Section(rawValue: section) {
            switch currentSection {
            case .createNewChannelSection:
                return 1

            case .currentChannelsSection:
                if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
                    return filteredChannels.count
                }
                else{
                return channels.count
                }
            }
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let reuseIdentifier = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == Section.createNewChannelSection.rawValue ? "NewChannel" : "ExistingChannel"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == Section.createNewChannelSection.rawValue {
            if let createNewChannelCell = cell as? CreateChannelCell {
                newChannelTextField = createNewChannelCell.newChannelNameField
            }
        } else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == Section.currentChannelsSection.rawValue {
            if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
                cell.textLabel?.text = filteredChannels[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].name
            } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = channels[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].name
        }
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == Section.currentChannelsSection.rawValue {
            var channel = channels
            if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
                channel = [filteredChannels[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]]
                channelRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: channel.name).observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in
                    let currentID = snapshot.key
                    print(currentID)
                })
            }
            else
            {
                channel = [channels[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]]
                channelRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: channel.name).observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in
                    let currentID = snapshot.key
                    print(currentID)
                })
            }

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowChannel", sender: channel)
        }
    }

}

    internal class Channel {
      internal let id: String
      internal let name: String

      init(id: String, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
      }
    }
```

Edit 2: I read about the prepare for segue, but this however won't execute correctly:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        if let channel = sender as? Channel {
        let chatVc = segue.destination as! channelMultiplayerViewController
        chatVc.channel = channel
        chatVc.channelRef = channelRef.child(channel.id)
    }
}
```

The prepare for segue function executes, but the if let channel = sender as? Channel is not, because it is nil.

Comment: Show the code where you are adding object in channels Also have you set id property of Channel object when you set it's name if you have set than you want to pass this channel ID to your new Screen ShowChannel?

Comment: I added more code, now you can exactly see what I am doing. I just want to retrieve the room's ID, not only for the creator, but also for people who wants to join that room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to query firebase for the key. The only problem with your current setup is that you would want to prevent duplicate names. The reason for this is that if you are not storing all the keys for each channel in app and have to query for the key, the only way to query the exact key is by the lone node "name". If a duplicate name exists then childAdded in the code I added to your did select row method will return two and there is no other data to help identify it.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == Section.currentChannelsSection.rawValue {
        var channel = channels
        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            channel = [filteredChannels[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]]
            channelRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: channel.name).observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in
                let currentID = snapshot.key
            })
        }
        else
        {
            channel = [channels[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]]
            channelRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: channel.name).observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in
                let currentID = snapshot.key
            })
        }
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowChannel", sender: channel)
    }
}
```

I would suggest you get the data for all of the channels on view did load:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    channelRef.observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in
        let data = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
        let key = snapshot.key
        let name = data["name"]
        let chnl = Channel.init(id:key, name:name)
        self.channels.append(chnl)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

When you use .childAdded a listener will be active for this VC so anytime you create a new channel this code will be called and reload your table.

Otherwise you can get they key directly when you create the channel:

```
@IBAction func createChannel(_ sender: AnyObject) {
if let name = newChannelTextField?.text {
    let newChannelRef = channelRef.childByAutoId()
    let channelItem = [
        "name": name
    ]
    newChannelRef.setValue(channelItem)
    let channelKey = newChannelRef.key
    let newChannel = Channel.init(id:channelKey, name:name)
    self.channels.append(newChannel)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

Just note if you go this route there are no active listeners for any new items added which means if another device is adding a channel then other devices will not get the update. Its better to pick up the newly created data from firebase via query and reload the table when you add your data to the array.

Here is a sample Channel class that should work for the above:

```
import Foundation
// import FirebaseDatabase // import this if you would like to use this class to handle data transactions

class Channel: NSObject {
    // change either of these to var if they should be mutable
    let id:String
    let name:String 
    // initialize
    init (_ id:String, name:String){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

This way you have a model object that you can use. If you are unfamiliar with MVC coding style you should check it out. It makes applications much more efficient. You could take this Channel model and add the data retrieval coding so that this class handles the data for your controller. This is well beyond the scope of your post though. For now this class should work.

EDIT from last comment:
Add your prepareforsegue method in both of the query blocks during channel selection instead of after the if block as its possible the prepare for segue is executing before the query completes. One thing to note though, and I used to do the same thing as you before I realized this; is that you don't have to run a query to get the data for the selected cell at this point because its in your local arrays. Well, currently you are only listening for added children. You can listen for removed and changed children as well so that your local data is always updated and then when you select the cell you can simply access the filteredChannels/channels arrays directly and push the channel through the prepareforsegue method. I started doing this instead because querying during table selection always leaded to odd bugs which I had to find creative ways around.

The childRemoved and childChanged queries can be implemented the same as your current .childAdded method given you would want to keep handlers for the listeners to remove them on page deinit. However you can ignore this if you don't allow channel removal or updates.

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer this. When I try to add your first code block to my project, I get the error " Value of type [Channel] has no member 'name'". Do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: Is the Channel class part of the same swift file? It would be better to create a new swift file named Channel.swift as a subclass of NSObject. I will update my answer with an example of this which should work for you.

Comment: Yes, the internal class was already a separated file, but sorry if I did not said that. I copied your code over my Channel.swift file, but I get the same error again...

Comment: It just sees the channel as a array, with no name or id property. I tried a lot but nothing works :( I added a prepare for segue function which I got from somewhere else, but the function won't execute correctly... I updated the question again.

Comment: It is possible your perform segue method is getting called before the query returns your data. See my updated answer, it was too long to add as a comment.

Comment: Thank you but I think the problem is in the prepare for segue, I made a different question for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333207/function-inside-prepareforsegue-will-not-execute I can not make this answer to work because the channel does not have a .name value :(

Comment: In the code you provided the channel class has an internal variable "name". Also read my last edit, I believe your prepare for segue is executing before Firebase is completing your query. Which means that the channel is nil. Or var channel = channels is the problem. You are setting channel initially as an array, but trying to pass it as a Channel object instead.

Comment: Looks like you updated the code so its not the query issue. Just need to pass a channel object instead of an array of channels.

Comment: Yes the problem is that it is an array. When trying to change it to Channel, I get a new error "Instance member 'name' can not be used on type 'Channel". I really have no clue how to do this simple task